# Direct/Indirect Effects When The Coefficients Have Opposite Signs?

Tags: regression-coefficients, mediation

Consider this model:

```
       # direct effects 
         Y ~ c1*X1+c2*X2
         
       # mediator
         M ~ a1*X1+a2*X2
         Y ~ b*M
         
       # indirect effect (a*b)
         ab1 := (a1*b)
         ab2 := (a2*b)
        
       # total effect
         direct := c1 + c2
         indirect := ab1 + ab2
```

Suppose `X1` and `X2` affect `M` but in opposite ways. So `c1 > 0` but `c2 < 0` then `ab1` and `ab2` will have opposite signs as well. When computing direct (indirect) effects they `c2` negates `c1` (`ab2` negates `ab1`) and direct (indirect) effect absolute value becomes less than both of `c1` and `c2` (`ab1` and `ab2`).

Now is it okay to compute direct effect like `direct := c1 - c2`? If it's not how do you intrepret direct(indirect) effect value here?